# I set three enum constants in a single enum variable, Is there a way to retrieve the enum constants from the enum variable as arrays?

Tags: c#

Below I set three enum constants in a single enum variable, Is there a way to retrieve the 
enum constants from the enum variable as arrays??

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Fruits fruit1 = Fruits.Apple;
        Fruits fruit2 = Fruits.Mango;

        Fruits mixedFruits = Fruits.Apple | Fruits.Orange | Fruits.Banana;

        string allFruits = mixedFruits.ToString();
        // I want the output to be "Apple, Orange, Banana"
        //Is this possible??
    }
}

public enum Fruits
{
    Apple,
    Mango,
    Orange,
    Grapes,
    Banana,
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `[Flags]` attribute and set enum value to be a power of 2:

```
[Flags]
public enum Fruits
{
    Apple = 1,
    Mango = 2,
    Orange = 4,
    Grapes = 8,
    Banana = 16
}
```

Now, `allFruits.ToString()` will print `"Apple, Orange, Banana"`.

Comment: Hi, after I set the enum value to be power of 2. Now the default value of the enum is set to zero which is nothing. Is it possible to set the apple as default value??  Ex: Fruits defaultFruit; defaultFruit is not set to any value. I can add None= 0, but is it possible to set the value Apple as default??

Comment: @Siva No, you can't change the default value. It will always be 0. That is why `Flags` enums should always have a `None` member whose value is 0. Microsoft's code analyzers will [warn about this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182149.aspx).